# How to return dictionary with specified index values

Tags: python

I am to read a file and return it as a dictionary where KEY are arg[2] indexed to 0 and the corresponding values are arg[3] & arg[5] in the rows of the file.csv where each value is a list of tuples. How can i do so, for instance without using imports.

**my take on this:**

```
dict= {}
with open('filename.csv') as file:
    file.readline()  
    for line in file:
        iso_code,continent,location,date,cases,newer_cases = (s.strip('"') for s in line.split(','))
        key = (location)
        if key not in answer: dict[key] = {}
```

Right now i just output a lot of duplicates of each country. Is there a smarter way to do this, and how do i know if each key is a list of tuples?

**snippet from file **

```
iso_code,continent,location,date,cases,newer_cases
aaa,bbb,helsinki,2020.05.18,5,4
aaa,bbb,helsinki,2020.05.22,4,8
aaa,bbb,copenhagen,2020.07.19,8,
aaa,bbb,oslo,2020.02.03,10,19
aaa,bbb,oslo,2019.02.18,21,2
aaa,bbb,oslo,2019.02.18,,13
```

**expected output** is the key should be the country names(str) and the values contains of a list of **date, cases**(str) tuples. If the case is empty then it should not be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check is this is your expected output

```
my_dict= {}

with open('filename.csv') as file:
    file.readline()  
    for line in file:
        iso_code,continent,location,date,cases,newer_cases = (s.strip('"') for s in line.split(','))
        if cases :
            if location not in my_dict:
                 my_dict[location] = [(date,cases)]
            else:
                my_dict[location].append((date,cases))
        

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know how to fix the error line 6 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 6).

Comment: I already executed my code but i didn't get any error, it is because your input csv file may have some extra commas for example run this code:  a,b,c,d,e,f = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g'.split(',')   you will get the same error because after spliting it is a tuple of 7 values but we are provided only 6 tuple values to assign.